# IndentationError: expected an indented block. I don't know where I wrote wrong

Tags: python

```
import random
r = random.randit(1,20)
while(True):
    inp = int(input())
    if(inp < r):
    \\\**print("wrong guess, enter a greater number")**///
    elif(inp > r):
    print("wrong guess, enter a smaller number")
else:
    print("congrats, you have guessed the right number")
    break;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. What's with the slashes and stars? You can [edit] your question if you want to remove them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import random
r = random.randint(1, 20)
while True:
    inp = int(input())
    if inp < r:
        print("wrong guess, enter a greater number")
    elif inp > r:
        print("wrong guess, enter a smaller number")
    else:
        print("congrats, you have guessed the right number")
        break
```

Comment: @wjandrea Python is whitespace sensitive unlike other languages. Also, comments start with a hashtag.

Comment: No parentheses in `if, while, for`. Comments are start with `#`. No semi-colon :)

Comment: IMHO integrating those feedback into your answer would greatly improve the quality of the post. Just a suggestion in passing.

Comment: @Erdogan Ah, so you mean it *is* Python code, but written with extra bits, in a non-Pythonic style. Yeah, adding that to the answer would help a lot.